# CSS Grid Items not filling cell

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

[When I say it doesnt fill the cell this is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IJbJ.png) I am having trouble with a grid I created. The items placed in the grid don't fill the cell. All the items seem to be positioned correctly and it is responsive but they won't actually fill the cell. Sorry if this is so obvious, I'm a newbie to HTML and CSS. I think that my code is not completely optimized and could a lot shorter but that's the way I found :').
Here the HTML code

```css
.about-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 1.5fr 1.2fr 0.8fr;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "sidebar main main main" "sidebar content1 content2 content3" "sidebar footer footer footer";
  grid-gap: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #004d40;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-grid nav {
  background: #a7ffeb;
  grid-area: nav;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid main {
  background: #84ffff;
  grid-area: main;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #sidebar {
  background: #18ffff;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #content1 {
  background: #6fffd2;
  grid-area: content1;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #content2 {
  background: #64ffda;
  grid-area: content2;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #content3 {
  background: #73ffba;
  grid-area: content3;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid footer {
  background: #1de9b6;
  grid-area: footer;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .about-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.4fr 0.4fr 2.2fr 1.2fr 1.2fr 1.2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "nav" "sidebar" "main" "content1" "content2" "content3" "footer";
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="about-bg">
  <div class="about-grid">
    <nav>Navbar</nav>
    <main>Main</main>
    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div id="content1">Content1</div>
    <div id="content2">Content2</div>
    <div id="content3">Content3</div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your problem, but I saw a different problem in your code. When you fill all the cells with large text, then your grid will go beyond the screen. Perhaps you meant this problem. You need to specify the `overflow-wrap: anywhere` rule for the `.about-grid` selector. Now the contents of the cells will depend on the width of the cells themselves.

To check how `overflow-wrap: anywhere` works. Run this snippet and remove the `overflow-wrap: anywhere` rule from the `.about-grid` selector and you should see what I'm talking about.

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.about-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 1.5fr 1.2fr 0.8fr;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "sidebar main main main" "sidebar content1 content2 content3" "sidebar footer footer footer";
  grid-gap: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #004d40;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere; /*add this it*/
}

.about-grid nav {
  background: #a7ffeb;
  grid-area: nav;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid main {
  background: #84ffff;
  grid-area: main;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #sidebar {
  background: #18ffff;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #content1 {
  background: #6fffd2;
  grid-area: content1;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #content2 {
  background: #64ffda;
  grid-area: content2;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #content3 {
  background: #73ffba;
  grid-area: content3;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid footer {
  background: #1de9b6;
  grid-area: footer;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .about-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.4fr 0.4fr 2.2fr 1.2fr 1.2fr 1.2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "nav" "sidebar" "main" "content1" "content2" "content3" "footer";
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="about-bg">
  <div class="about-grid">
    <nav>Navbar</nav>
    <main>Main</main>
    <div id="sidebar">SidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebarSidebar</div>
    <div id="content1">Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1Content1</div>
    <div id="content2">Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2Content2</div>
    <div id="content3">Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3Content3</div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: I tried adding the overflow-wrap: anywhere and it did not do anything in my code. I added an image in my question so that it is a bit more clear. Thanks tho

Comment: if you did as in my answer and you failed, then the problem is not with this code you gave. Add more html and css code to your question.

Comment: oh, you're right! I deleted one line and now it's working! Thank you so much!

Comment: always glad to help )

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to remove the little margins between cells? If so, then setting `grid-gap: 0` will do it:

Demo:

```css
.about-grid
{
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 1.5fr 1.2fr 0.8fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav nav"
    "sidebar main main main"
    "sidebar content1 content2 content3"
    "sidebar footer footer footer";
    
  /*The only thing I changed, grid-gap*/
  grid-gap: 0;
  
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #004d40;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-grid nav {
  background: #a7ffeb;
  grid-area: nav;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid main {
  background: #84ffff;
  grid-area: main;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #sidebar {
  background: #18ffff;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #content1 {
  background: #6fffd2;
  grid-area: content1;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #content2 {
  background: #64ffda;
  grid-area: content2;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid #content3 {
  background: #73ffba;
  grid-area: content3;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid footer {
  background: #1de9b6;
  grid-area: footer;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.about-grid a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .about-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.4fr 0.4fr 2.2fr 1.2fr 1.2fr 1.2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "nav"
      "sidebar"
      "main"
      "content1"
      "content2"
      "content3"
      "footer";
  }
}
```

```html
 <main class="about-bg">
    <div class="about-grid">
        <nav>Navbar</nav>
        <main>Main</main>
        <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
        <div id="content1">Content1</div>
        <div id="content2">Content2</div>
        <div id="content3">Content3</div>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
     </div>
     
</main>
```